# Поиск кириллицы в строке текстового файла

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть такая задача. Загружается текстовый файл (.txt). В этом файле есть 4 колонки такого вида:

```
001 IBSO 1 Абвг Деёж12345
```

При загрузке файла надо с четвертой колонки, убрать кириллицу и оставить только цифры, т.е. вместо `Абвг Деёж12345` должен загружаться `12345`.

Comment: *В этом файле есть 4 колонки, такого вида: 001 IBSO 1 Абвг Деёж12345.* Я лично считаю, что их пять.

Comment: да, если так посмотреть 5, но в самом файле это 4 колонка идет как название. И у некоторых название длинное и они сохранены через пробелы. Например: Автозапчасти машины12345. В некоторых строках идет просто: запчасти12345

Comment: А при чём тут plsql?

Comment: При том что, задача на pl+, поэтому выбора не было при подачи заявки. Там только был вариант plsql...

Answer (score 2):

Такой блок даст желаемый результат:

```sql
var res varchar2 (128)
declare
    str constant varchar2 (128) := '001 IBSO 1 Абвг Деёж12345';
begin
    :res := regexp_replace (
        str, 
        '(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+([А-яЁё ]+(\d+))', '\1 \2 \3 \5');
end;
/
```

```
RES
----------------
001 IBSO 1 12345
```